# Unable to retrieve data from JSON file using jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getjson

I am new to Javascript and jQuery and I am trying to retrieve data from a JSON file using getJSON method in jQuery. However I am unable to do so. Here is the code:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <title>JSON Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    console.log("Hi");
    $.getJSON('red.json', function(data){
    console.log("This is the Data" + data["Live Births"])});
    var response = $.getJSON( "red.json", function() {
        console.log( "success" );
       })
       .done(function() {
         console.log( "second success" );
       })
       .fail(function() {
         console.log( "error" );
       })
       .always(function() {
         console.log( "complete" );
       });
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

JSON:

```
{"Live Births" : [
        [11.925, 76.9502],
        [11.896, 76.9492],
        [11.990, 76.9602],
        [11.911, 76.9402],
        [11.978, 76.8902]
    ],

    "Still Births" : [
        [11.986, 76.9402],
        [11.896, 76.9602],
        [11.966, 76.8992],
        [11.916, 76.8902],
        [11.946, 76.9002]
    ]}
```

Awaiting your responses.

Regards,

Jones

[A fiddle Demo to the problem is added](http://jsfiddle.net/QB5MC/)

Comment: where is your red.json located?

Comment: Check console to see the error and update your question.

Comment: There is no error. My console is open.

Comment: add a **;** after your console.log('Hi')

Comment: Tried that. Still not working.

Comment: Try to add a .fail handler to see what happens

Comment: Can you update on what is printed on your console?

Comment: I have added the handler for fail as well. The output on the console is as - 'Hi' 'Error' 'Complete'. Which means the getJSON is failing.

Comment: The update code you mentioned works as well for me! I get 
Hi
This is the Data11.925,76.9502,11.896,76.9492,11.99,76.9602,11.911,76.9402,11.978,76.8902

success

second success

complete

Comment: This is creepy. What can go wrong in my system with the code being same?

Comment: Chek my Edit status on my anwser and try that.

Comment: Could it be that your "red.json" file is in a different location?

Comment: No No. It is in the same location as index.html.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have implement your code at my local server and it works fine.
Here is what I used:

**HTML:**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
    <title>JSON Test</title>
</head>

<body>
<script type="text/javascript">
    alert("Hi");
    $.getJSON('red.json', function(data){
    alert("This is the Data" + data["Live Births"])});
</script>


</body>
</html>
```

The only difference is the link to the jQuery library ( maybe is this the problem at your side? ).

**JSON (red.json):**

```
{
    "Live Births" : [
        [11.925, 76.9502],
        [11.896, 76.9492],
        [11.990, 76.9602],
        [11.911, 76.9402],
        [11.978, 76.8902]
    ],

    "Still Births" : [
        [11.986, 76.9402],
        [11.896, 76.9602],
        [11.966, 76.8992],
        [11.916, 76.8902],
        [11.946, 76.9002]
    ]
}
```

Located in the same directory as your html file.

**Edit:**

This is what I have done:

Create a new file ( index.html ) and paste your html code in it. Then create a new file red.json with your json data. Put those two files in one directory and open index.html.

Comment: I have just copied it right away and tested it and it doesn't seem to work! I am running from the localhost so that cant be the error. This issue has been eating me up since a while now.

Comment: Do you get the first alert message 'Hi'?

Comment: Yes I am getting that.

Comment: Failed to load resource: net::ERR_BLOCKED_BY_CLIENT http://apiluckyleapnet-a.akamaihd.net/gsrs?is=cbswcgp10&bp=PB&g=f5810f79-5d38-4612-aa78-d68ad8a098cc
Hi (index):12
error (index):22
complete (index):25 ----> This is my console after following your instructions. I am looking at other ways of implementing this now.

Comment: Copy the content of [jQuery library](http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js) to seperated file called **jquery.js** and put this in the same directory as your index.html and red.json. Also change the url of the script tag to **jquery.js**. And now?

Comment: I followed every isntruction. Copied the content into jquery.js and included that in the script and placed it in the same folder as the other files. But i still cant get it through.

Comment: Here is my project, download it and try it. [jQuery json data example](https://www.wetransfer.com/downloads/54eae23994bceb4f0ffb12e60ab3091420140519123932/4d7e1d9c7f20c75a2dd19336c94e8cde20140519123932/1d210c)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/53963/discussion-between-vdesign-and-jones)

Comment: Hey VDesign, Yes It has worked and I replied on the same mail id that you had sent it from. Thank you very much. :) However, I still do not understand where I went wrong.

Comment: Strange... Did you checked your code with my code to see some differences? Please don't forgot to rate my anwser.

Comment: Yes Yes I did and it was exactly the same. I guess the problem was with jquery.js. That was the only difference.

Answer (score 0):

Please try with this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  console.log("Hi")
  $(function(){
    $.getJSON('red.json', function(data){
    console.log("This is the Data" + data)});
  });
```

// please add these handler

```
var response = $.getJSON( "red.json", function() {
 console.log( "success" );
})
.done(function() {
  console.log( "second success" );
})
.fail(function() {
  console.log( "error" );
})
.always(function() {
  console.log( "complete" );
});


</script>
```

Comment: I tried that as well. It is still not working. Is there something wrong with the JSON file format?

Comment: Please follow VDesign note once. You have correct JSON format.

Comment: The ouput I get to that is - 'hi' 'error' 'complete'